# Firebase database offline capability

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app using firebase and have put functionality for offline storage i.e setPresistanceEnabled to true and have synced database properly. The problem I get is that data is stored offline but only gets loaded after I close that respective activity and restart it again. Have anyone faced this problem? I will share all code if any of you ask. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that either the context you are using is not properly indexed. If you are using fragments please use view.getActivity() or getActivity() for firebase context.

The another problem is that when you set the LinearLayout.
Strictly please donot use 
setFixedSize(boolean b);
Do not use this and test it.
Let me know if it helps you. Regards.